# A (syndicated) blog with the best of WPA?

Tags: discussion, promotion, blog

When I read some of the answers on this site, they are practically independent articles on great WordPress programming. I think we can easily re-use their content to get a "best-of WordPress Answers" blog, which would [reward answers to hard questions](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16/hard-questions-vs-easy-questions) that otherwise might go unnoticed.

The articles would be based on great questions and answers, but they would offer more. Sometimes a WPA question is narrow but the answer solves more problems than just that. The article could tell this. Sometimes the top answer is good, but other answers are good too. The article could combine them. Sometimes it is just interesting to know the background to an answer: how did you come up with it, and how can we learn to do this ourselves?

But even better, we could **partner with existing WordPress blogs** and let them publish some articles, which would bring their audience to our site. We could probably make an agreement that they get to publish the chosen articles a bit earlier (say, one week), but that we still can publish all articles on our own WPA blog. Of course, if the author has a personal blog, he or she is free to publish it there too.

I think we can offer two kinds of articles: long-form and quick tips. We can find different syndication partners for both.

Comment: Are you proposing that we start a blog, and have it hosted by the SO team somewhere (blog.wordpress.stackexchange?)?. If so, I'm not convinced (yet) that would be a good idea. You'd quickly run into the problem of who can contribute, who's in charge, etc. However, encouraging existing, widely read WP blogs to use content from this site is a GREAT idea. They already can, without permission (all content is creative commons licensed), but we should definitely encourage anyone to do so.

Comment: @tnorthcutt: My main goal is promotion of the site, and placing content on existing blogs would be the best way to do that quickly. But, I was thinking that they might be easier to convince if we would already write (most of) the content for them. If we do that, it would only be logical that we group all content that appeared in different external blogs on one blog specific to this site. We could then also use this site-related blog to post site-specific content ("Get to know a WPA user!"), without [abusing Meta](http://meta.wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/144/is-mikeschinkel-a-company).

Comment: That makes more sense - sort of a collection of guest posts that WPA members have posted elsewhere, with some original/exclusive content thrown in?

Answer (score 4):

I've started working on this over the past couple of days, if you're interested in helping me write/modify/edit content, or if you have connections with some existing awesome WP blogs, could you email me -tom at- conceptcoding dot co dot uk

Comment: Very cool Thomas, and sorry I didn't reply to your mail yet. Do you have something you can show us already? Some drafts of articles? Maybe you could put them on Google Docs so we can all try and suggest edits?

Comment: @Jan, sorry for late reply, I've been pretty busy recently so this has fallen on the backburner. Have got a few hours now so I'll start drafting some content together.