# Good WordPress blogs for promoting this site?

Tags: discussion, promotion

What are the best WordPress blogs, that attract a wide and smart audience, which we would like to see participate on WordPress Answers? This is related to the [blog proposal](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143/a-syndicated-blog-with-the-best-of-wpa), I think we can realize this idea quicker if we get a concrete idea of who we want to target.

**Update:** Of course, *we* are developers too, so the blogs you read by definition have an intelligent audience. Where do you go for quality WordPress articles?

Probably best one suggestion per answer, so we can vote on it. I [can't make this question Community Wiki anymore](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67039/what-can-we-do-to-make-community-wiki-better/67192#67192), but rep doesn't count on Meta so that should not matter too much.

Comment: Not sure about "blogs participate"... You mean WP designer/developers with popular blogs to invite here?

Comment: @Rarst: no, I mean the audience of the blog. What blogs have a level that makes sure they are read by technical people, not just "content people".

Comment: *@Jan Fabry* - Great idea. Those sites are interested in their advertising revenue so the biggest challenge is to come up with an incentive for them. Maybe we could build a set of WordPress widgets that would serve up lists of content here based on answers that reference articles on their site? Maybe we can work through some game mechanics to motivate authors and publishers of these blogs to participate and to also to display the widgets? *(We'd need to focus on what makes them most motivated to participate.)*

Comment: Joel on Software blogged about the site already: A new WordPress Stack Exchange (31 Aug 2010) - http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2010/08/31.html

Answer (score 10):

### [Smashing Magazine](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/tag/wordpress/)

Answer (score 7):

## [Digging into WordPress](http://digwp.com/)

Answer (score 6):

## [WP Engineer](http://wpengineer.com/)

Answer (score 4):

## [Weblog Tools Collection](http://weblogtoolscollection.com/)

Answer (score 3):

## [Perishable Press](http://perishablepress.com/)

Answer (score 3):

### [WP Beginner](http://www.wpbeginner.com/)

Answer (score 3):

## [WP Candy](http://wpcandy.com/)

On a side note they [published](http://wpcandy.com/reports/wordpress-answers-site-now-on-stack-exchange) a news item that I submitted to them about WordPress Answers

Answer (score 3):

### [Think Vitamin](http://thinkvitamin.com/?s=wordpress&search=Search)

Answer (score 2):

### http://net.tutsplus.com/

Answer (score 1):

### [Web Designer Wall](http://www.webdesignerwall.com/tag/wordpress/)

Answer (score 1):

[**Mark On Wordpress**](http://markjaquith.wordpress.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Contact all the bloggers in this list: http://populair.eu/wordpress/ (second and third column)

Answer (score 1):

### [Yoast](http://www.yoast.com/)

Answer (score 0):

### [Mashable](http://www.mashable.com/tag/wordpress/)