# WPA Community Blog

Tags: discussion, blog

I saw on Twitter ([1](http://twitter.com/#!/tnorthcutt/status/45237274568437761), [2](http://twitter.com/#!/EricMann/status/45238941833637888)) that there would be some interest in expanding Blog Overflow to include WPA. :)

I originally intended it to be a place for a WordPress Answers community blog but got sidetracked after dreaming up an elaborate plan where each site would have their own community blog (I think Ivo is exploring this now though) and I got as far as importing Gaming's WP.com blog and setting up a site for the people of Super User before I became snowed under with work. This was a good 6 months ago.

Now the Super User blog has some official blessing, I think it's probably a good time to put the site to it's intended use.

I'm looking some suggestions for lines we'd like to pursue in terms of content. SU has a question of the week feature, where the content is pretty much lifted from SU with some background blurb, but we have a lot of quality content that could be turned into pretty lengthy articles.

Pop over to [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6/stoppress) and ping me (@Thomas should do) to get a user account.

> Related:
>
> - [A (syndicated) blog with the best of WPA?](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143/a-syndicated-blog-with-the-best-of-wpa)

<sub>(also, with hindsight, the domain is pretty poor, I know.)</sub>

Comment: We now have a set a guidelines for Stack Exchange Community blogs, so make sure you check out http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91407/area-51-for-blogs/91509#91509

Answer (score 8):

This is a great idea!

Now that there are multiple communities with an interest in a blog (Super User, Gaming, Wordpress), we might look at hosting this on our own servers -- and giving you guys full control over it to run and administer.

From my perspective, I would rather see

`blog.superuser.com`
`blog.gaming.stackexchange.com` (or perhaps `blog.stackexchange.com/gaming`?)
`blog.wordpress.stackexchange.com` (or perhaps `blog.stackexchange.com/wordpress`?)

Mostly, if we want to make this a first-class function of our communities we should pull it a little more in-house so we can offer superior control for changes, etc.

Comment: I very much like this idea. A lot.

Comment: This was kinda what I originally hoped for. :)

Comment: (I got bitten by accidentally making a comment and then editing it in place) This was what I was hoping the end product would be (eventually), and so I would be fully behind this. In terms of domain, `blog.site.stackexchange.com` follows the current 'standard'.

Comment: we have already been discussing this on E&R and are going to see which users are interested in being active on the blog. We will then try to set one up for use also. This idea of yours sounds great!