# What ever happened to the WPSE blog?

Tags: discussion, blog

This was brought up a while back, [WPA Community Blog](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/481/wpa-community-blog), I think it's a great idea. I did not even know about stack blogs until I read the post today from thier "[official](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/11/the-best-of-blog-overflow-october-2011/)" one.

I don't really have a blog of my own, so I would be able to help out.

Thoughts?

Reference and guidlines:
http://blogoverflow.com/
http://blogoverflow.com/getting-started/

Comment: We'd be happy to create one if it is something the community wants and will contribute to...and still want to contribute to in a few months. (:  Let me know if I can help as you work through seeing if there's viability here.

Answer (score 8):

Same thing that is happening to the rest of the site - lack of expert/human resources.

I would love to have a blog (I mean, strong WordPress resource *without* blog? nonsense), but the thought of dealing with it on top of everything else on site makes me howl. Jan Fabry was one of the more interested in blog, but he got busy at work and doesn't show up much lately.

Also I would be rooting for extreme editorial oversight for blog (I don't know how this is handled at other network blogs). There are enough crappy WP blogs around and it would be poor of us to add one more to the mix. Which doesn't help human resources issue at all.

Answer (score 0):

While I'm not the brightest and most certainly not the most experienced when it comes to WordPress, I happen to be available for writing about whichever topics are required - I'm not great with ideas so if you give me one, I could write the hell out of it. Other than that, a community around a publishing platform that is not used by the community's most reliable source - the site itself, is well, strange and whether or not it will have a ton of activity, it should still be there. I mean, one article per month wouldn't hurt nobody, if that's what we'd get, which I think is highly unlikely.