# Should the number of upvotes correlate to the quality of the answer?

Tags: discussion, reputation, voting, up-votes

*This is related to, but not a duplicate of, [this question](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16/hard-questions-vs-easy-questions).*

There are many times when I see an good and/or accepted answer, and I start to upvote it, but then I stop because it already has more upvotes than seems appropriate, given the quality/difficulty of the answer. There's nothing *wrong* with the answer, but it doesn't seem like it's earned 10 upvotes when it probably only took them 2 minutes.

Is that wrong? Are there any official criteria for what's worthy of an upvote (other than "This answer is useful")?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What is worthy of **your** upvote is **entirely up to you**.

The resulting sum of upvotes is expression of community opinion, but it goes from individuals to the sum. Not the other way around. Community doesn't and shouldn't dictate you this.

Always vote in line with what you think about the post.

Site docs [put it simply like this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up):

> **When should I vote up?**
>
> Whenever you encounter a question or answer that you feel is
>   especially useful, vote it up!

PS only be careful not to fall into trap of trend - adding upvote or downvote just because post already has a bunch of either.

Comment: Cool, thanks :)